# Can't use silverlight namespace

Tags: silverlight, xaml, reference

Whenever I try to reference the following namespace in my XAML, the code compiles and the project starts, but the InitializeComponent method throws an error.  Here's the XAML reference:

xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"

and here's the use of ExtendedVisualStateManager

```
<ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
```

The error is this:

```
The type 'ExtendedVisualStateManager' was not found because 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions' is an unknown namespace. [Line: 19 Position: 37]
```

Is there a new namespace I need to use to use this control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some facts.

1. The Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll version 4.0.5.0 contains the namespace `Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core`.
2. This `Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core` contains the type `ExtendedVisualStateManager`.
3. The Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll version 4.0.5.0 carries a `XmlnsDefinition` that maps the URL "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" to the namespace `Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core`.

Hence a project referencing version 4.0.5.0 of Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll can contain Xaml using `xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"` that can then contain `ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager`.

You'll note I've repeated the version number a few times.  If you do have an interactions dll referenced in a Silverlight 4 project but your code doesn't work then perhaps its the wrong version.  However in that case Dan's answer should still have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Silverlight application has a reference to the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions assembly.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
    ...other namespaces... />
    <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
        <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
    </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I already had that assembly referenced and tried using your style of referencing the assembly, but a new error was thrown :
The type 'ExtendedVisualStateManager' was not found because 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions' is an unknown namespace. [Line: 19 Position: 37]

Answer (score 2):

I had everything correct per the other answers and like you, the problem still existed.  It was failing at runtime on a usercontrol in my project (and that project did reference `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`).

However, that usercontrol was being used on a form in another project.  Once I added the reference to `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` to the outer project, the runtime error was solved.  I was not loading assemblies dynamically and so I'm not 100% certain why this was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look in your project's properties. Find the references (Microsoft.Expression.Interactions or/and other "Expression" assemblies you may use, and set the "Copy Local" property to TRUE and try it again.

Answer (score -1):

None of the answers solved this puzzling problem to me.

Apparently I needed  [Microsoft Expression Blend SDK for Silverlight 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3062).

Installing it has solved the issue.

Comment: Well if you think answer is bad, you could comment without -1. Anyway I found all answers here very weird and top rated answer looks useless to me, doesn't lead to solution at all.